# Multiply elements of a list with natural numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, numpy

I have a list that look like this :

```
l=[0.1,0.5,2.1,3.3]
```

I want to multiply each of these numbers by consecutive natural numbers and form a list out of it.for instance

```
newlist=[1*0.1,2*0.5,3*2.1,4*3.3]
```

I have the following code:

```
l=[0.1,0.5,2.1,3.3]
s = np.arange(1,len(l)+1)
np.multiply(l,s)
```

Just wondering if there is a method, inbuilt or otherwise, in which I don't have to define s.

T
Thank you.

Comment: Why you are not satisfied with your approach? It's just one command after all!

Comment: just `l*s` is good

Comment: I was hoping to know if there is an in-built function for this.

Comment: Your code is as performant as it can probably get as you are using `numpy`'s vectorized multiplication.

Comment: how can that be more "in-built" than a simple operator?

Comment: Maybe `A = np.array([0.1,0.5,2.1,3.3]); res = np.arange(1, A.shape[0]+1) * A`. Not much diff.

Comment: @bobrobbob in-built as in I don't need to define 's'  specifically.

Comment: Just do `l * s`. Single, 'built-in' command and the fastest.

Comment: @Tapasya.A you should update your question with that comment (and the answer would be no)

Comment: You will always have to define `s`, but you don't have to do it as explicit as you are doing it: `l * range(1, len(l) + 1)`. Just make sure `l` is a numpy array

Comment: @DeepSpace, Sure. Thanks.

Comment: @Tapasya.A See my answer with full example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps the most "native" way this can be done is by making sure `l` is a numpy array, then:

```
import numpy as np

l = np.array([0.1, 0.5, 2.1, 3.3])
print(l * range(1, len(l) + 1))
# array([ 0.1,  1. ,  6.3, 13.2])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map), [`itertools.count`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.count) and [`operator.mul`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.mul):

```
import operator
import itertools

l=[0.1,0.5,2.1,3.3]
res = list(map(operator.mul, l, itertools.count(1)))
```

Here you have a [live example](https://repl.it/repls/OrneryTediousChief)

Comment: why the downvoting?

Comment: I believe OPs code already has better performance, especially for longer inputs since they are taking advantage of `numpy`'s vectorization

Comment: Ok then, OP can simply use `l * s` which is still 'bulit-in` *and* more perofrmant

Answer (score 0):

I think a simple python list comprehension can be efficient for your problem.

```
>>> l=[0.1,0.5,2.1,3.3]
>>> l
[0.1, 0.5, 2.1, 3.3]
>>> ll = [item * val for item, val in zip(l, range(1, len(l) + 1))]
>>> ll
[0.1, 1.0, 6.300000000000001, 13.2]
```

Answer (score -1):

There are probably many ways to do this:

```
[a*b for a,b in zip(l,range(1,1+len(l)))]
```